# jquery inside the ui-view doesn't initiate when I navigate away and come back. AngularJs1.6.1

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm building in Angular 1.6. Is there any general reason as to why jQuery would stop working when you navigate to a page and come back to it. But if you refresh, it all works fine. No errors in the console.

There is nothing special about the HTML

```
html
  body
    header
    main ui-view
    footer

    script - jquery
    script - angular
    script - angular dependencies
    script - controllers
    script - main.js <-- 
  /body
/html
```

Inside the main.js I have a Slimscroll code like this

```
$(function() {
    $('.scroll').slimScroll({
        height: '100%'
    });
});
```

I attached that `.scroll` class to anything I want a slimscroll applied to. Some of the places are the body, the menu dropdowns and some widgets in the dashboard that have a hidden overflow and fixed height.

When I enter the page (dashboard.html) the view loads fine with the slimscroll working. When I navigate away and come back, the slimscroll is no longer working. Now here is the kicker!

- Only the items inside the view are affected! The slimscroll script still works for the menu drodowns and body.
- The slimscroll is the one I am using as an example, but actually, nothing really works (vector maps, morris charts, etc) basically nothing that works with jquery
- If I refresh the view, it all works
- No errors in the console

What gives?

p.s. Yes, I am using document.ready but it doesn't matter because this code below is outside of the document.ready and it also doesn't work until reloaded.

It is almost as if jquery is blocked and not passing through the DOM, but in that same breath, if that was the case, then the scripts in the header wouldn't work either. How can the view be the only one affected?

```
history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    history.go(1);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.scroll').slimScroll({
    height: '100%'
});
```

This does 2 things - selects all elements with css class and apply jquery plugin to each. It will not apply it to new elements. When view changes/back/forward - ui-view element is recreated with all contained html elements. Thats actually it. (This is not related to ui-view, but true for any dynamically created elements - in fact I am curious how something may work in your case)

How it should be? Put all jquery to directives, so when new element is created and compiled - angular will run this directive.

```
.directive('scroll', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(sc, elem, attrs) {
      $(elem).slimScroll({
        height: '100%'
      });
    }
  }
})
```